# ¿Como puedo guardar resultados de node-fetch en una variable?

Tags: javascript, json, api, fetch

Ya he hecho bots antes, pero en este caso, quiero usar una api de servidores de minecraft para que cambie su estado cada 5 segundos con informacion obtenida de la API, tambien, un simple comando de embed que envia información.
Aquí esta el código:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const datos = require("./datos.json");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
let prefix = datos.prefix


client.on('ready', () => {
  fetch(`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/mc.bouncegaming.es`).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
    let bgip = json.ip
    let bgport = json.port
    let bgplayersonline = json.players.online
    let bgplayersmax = json.players.max
    let bgmotd = json.motd.clean
    let bgversion = json.version
  })
  const estados = [
    " ", 
    "mc.bouncegaming.es",
    "Hay "+bgplayersonline+"/"+bgplayersmax+" conectados.",
    "Version: "+bgversion+"."
    ]; 

  console.log("Bot encendido.")
  setInterval(() => {
      const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (estados.length - 1) + 1); 
      client.user.setActivity(estados[index]); 
  }, 5000); 


           client.on("message", (message)  => {
            let member = message.member;
            const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

            if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix+"statusmc")) {
                  const embedbg1 = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                  .setColor(0x1A85CC)
                  .setTitle('BounceGaming')
                  .setThumbnail("https://bouncegaming.es/files/logo512.png")
                  .setDescription('https://discord.gg/FzkuFJg')
                  .addField('Usuarios conectados:', bgplayersonline+"/"+bgplayersmax, true)
                  .addField('IP:', bgip+":"+bgport, true)
                  .addBlankField()
                  .addField('MOTD:', bgmotd, true)
                  .addField('Version:', bgversion, true)
                message.channel.send(embedbg1)
            }
            

        
        })
});
           
client.login(datos.token);
```

**Peeero consigo este error:**

C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\index.js:20
    "Hay "+bgplayersonline+"/"+bgplayersmax+" conectados.",
           ^

ReferenceError: bgplayersonline is not defined
    at Client. (C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\index.js:20:12)
[90m    at Client.emit (events.js:215:7)[39m
    at WebSocketConnection.triggerReady (C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:125:17)
    at WebSocketConnection.checkIfReady (C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:141:61)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\GuildCreate.js:13:31)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:105:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\node_modules\[4mdiscord.js[24m\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\botBounceGaming\discordapimc\node_modules\[4mws[24m\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
[90m    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)[39m

Agradezco toda ayuda para conseguir guardar la informacion en una variable para usar la informacion fuera del .then(json => {
//Blah Blah Blah})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es bastante simple, lo que dices es lo que necesitas. Para poder aplicarlo seria de la siguiente manera:

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
let bgData = {};
fetch(`https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/mc.bouncegaming.es`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => {
    bgData = {
      bgip: json.ip,
      bgport: json.port,
      bgplayersonline: json.players.online,
      bgplayersmax: json.players.max,
      bgmotd: json.motd.clean,
      bgversion: json.version
    };
  });
await delay(5000);
console.log(bgData); // Solo estará completa cuando se resuelva la promesa (fetch)
```

El problema que estas teniendo es que dentro de `then()` estas declarando las variables con `let` y eso hace que esas variables definidas esten solo accesibles en el scope de esa función. La limitación del scope de las variables declaradas con `let` es por bloque, en tu caso no tenes ningún bloque dentro de esa función por lo que esta accesible dentro de esa función completa.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let